# Still unknown class in Interface Builder file, have checked other answers

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift

I know this question has been asked a few times before, and I have checked all the solutions offered. 
 - My storyboard viewcontroller is linked to a custom class. This seems to work since you can click the little arrow, and it opens up the correct class file.
 - The custom class is included in the project.
 - The storyboard source file shows the correct name for the class.

I still get the error "Unknown class KnorkMans in Interface Builder file"
This screenshot shows all the steps I have taken:

[image: class_not_found]

Comment: Did you link to view or view controller ?

Comment: Yes, that's the second image in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to manually select module VerwijderMij.

Comment: xCode automatically tracks in project classes as project module classes, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, The thing is that Objective-C classes are internally known exactly the same as the class name. Therefore you don't need to specify the module. Swift classes are internally know differently. If you execute a NSStringFromClass(theObject.dynamicType) then you will get _TtC12VerwijderMij9KnorkMans That is why the module needs to be known.